# How to get ListView selection color value?

Tags: android-listview, android, android-drawable

I'm developing a custom control and would like to use same color ListView control uses to highlight selected item.

I tried to use `context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background)`
and then use `setBackgroundDrawable()` on my view, but the background is still transparent.

I don't want to use states and I just need a color value or drawable I can use on my control as a background.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option is to use a selector like that on your xml on your listview:

```
 <ListView 
   ....
   android:listSelector="@drawable/selectable_background"
   ..../>
```

Then on you drawable folder you add an xml file like this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >

    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background" />

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and again on your drawable folder you add this other xml file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

     <solid android:color="@color/green" />

</shape>
```

and on your drawable-hdpi you add this 9-patch file (change the color or the file or use this web to create your own one http://android-holo-colors.com/):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33565803/StackOverFlowExamples/list_focused.9.png

Like this you should be able to have your customise highlight color on your listview.

EDIT:

Background of the clickable view :

```
android:background="@drawable/pressed_button"
```

Selector for the default ListView highlight color (pressed_button.xml inside drawable folder):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
      android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: But I don't want my own color. I want to reuse exactly the same color standard ListView uses. And my control is not based on ListView. It's a custom control.

Comment: Actually I highly recommend you http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html to customise your app to your own environment colors.

Comment: The default color change in different versions and phones... so is it what you want? Just the default one whatever it is... Why dont you customise your app? it is recommended and you can offer a nice presentation of your own enviroment

Comment: Yep, I just want the default ListView selection color. I don't want to customize the whole theme to make sure my custom selection color doesn't clash with other colors.

Comment: Anyway if it is what you want... did you try something like set the background property on the xml of your clickable view to : android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. The background is transparent. I have also tried setting the state for the drawable before using it as a background, but that didn't work either.

Comment: and did you try it inside a selector? I have just edit my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32530/discussion-between-jpardogo-and-lev)

Answer (score 0):

Well the list selector drawable is (usually) transparent in its default state. So you have to change the state first.

The pressed state could be used for example:

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
drawable.setState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed});
x.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Where `x` is your view.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've tried using android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_focused, and both combined. But the background is still transparent :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

For example you need the get the **list item view**  by using below code 
int visiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 
View view = listview.getChildAt(1 - visiblePosition);

// To get the color of particular listview item and set it, 
View newView = listview.getChildAt(5 - visiblePosition); 
newView.setBackgroundColor(((ColorDrawable) view.getBackground()).getColor());